# Why does Windows 10 stop seeing an internal hard drive while I am using a program on it?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hard-drive-failure

Fundamental question: is my drive failing and I should clone the information off it onto a new (preferably SSD) hard drive?

The computer is running Windows 10.0.19041 Build 19041, with a Gigabyte H370 wifi mobo. There are two hard drives (I don't run any external), one of which is a 250Gb Western Digital SSD. This is the c:\ drive. The other is a 2Tb Seagate Barracuda. The latter is partitioned into the d:\ and e:\ drives. I got the SSD when the machine was built, about 2.5 years ago. When we got the build, we took the Seagate out of my previous machine and put it into this one. The Seagate is possibly around 8 years old.

[image]

Over the past couple of days, the Seagate has been disappearing from File Explorer. What has happened is that I am playing a MMO (program is stored on e:). Suddenly the game crashes. In File Explorer, only the c:\ drive is shown. However, a concurrent application - such as Discord - which is on my c:\ drive, remained working.

Rebooting brings the Seagate drive back.

From what I have read, I should expect catastrophic hard drive failure. However, a Windows 10 SMART scan was passed today. I have run the SeaTools for Windows program, and it found nothing. The firmware revision code for the Seagate is CC25. I haven't tried any other disk management tools.

I have not changed the hardware on the PC. I have neither downloaded nor installed any new software, apart from the SeaTools in my effort to discover the problem.

There doesn't seem to be a consistent timing in the drive disappearance (for wont of a better term). It does seem associated with having the MMO running, but with only two occurrences I don't know if this is just coincidence. The age of the Seagate makes me suspect it could be the age of the drive causing the problems. However, I don't understand why a full check of the drive using SeaTools is showing up nothing.

I'm leaning towards the conclusion that the hard drive is failing, but idiosyncratically enough that the detection software cannot find anything wrong. I'm also leaning towards getting a 1T SSD as the replacement drive as it appears I don't need anything like 2T. But then I don't know whether I am limited to a SATA SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Seagate is possibly around 8 years old. Over the past couple of
> days, the Seagate has been disappearing from File Explorer.

I much agree that the hard drive appears to be failing.

Get the Seagate HDD test app and test the drive.

Also run CHKDSK to also check.

Important:  Back up important data right away so you can relax a bit and plan the transition to SSD.

Comment: Thanks. Given that the symptom is consistent with a failing drive - with my situation being a bit odd compared to others in that failure occurs while I program on the failing drive is running. I'm looking through SSD specs, and will clone the drive. I have all my important files stored on the cloud. I'm working on those on another machine, and have turned off my link to the cloud on this machine so it can't corrupt the cloud data.